# Translating scikit-learn version 0.17 code to verion 0.20

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian

Hi I was wonder if anyone has any idea how to translate the below scikit-learn version 0.17 code to version 0.20

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess
gp = GaussianProcess(corr='cubic', theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1E-1,
                     random_start=100)
xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
yfit, MSE = gp.predict(xfit[:, np.newaxis], eval_MSE=True)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GaussianProcess is now split between [GaussianProcessRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor) and [GaussianProcessClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier)

Comment: Yes I am very much aware of this, the problem is that you need to pick a kernel for the covariance matrix and the example above shows that the kernel = `corr=cubic`, but there's not an equivalent kernel in the available options in `gaussian_process.kernels.`.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the same snippet of code in the book
"Python Data Science Handbook" by Jake VanderPlas.
I did this,

```
    from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
    from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
    
    kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))
    gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
    gp.fit(xdata[:,np.newaxis],ydata)
    xfit = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
    yfit, sigma = gp.predict(xfit[:,np.newaxis], return_std=True)
    dyfit = 2*sigma
```

it is not the same as in the book but it works,
I followed this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpr-noisy-targets-py) on the official site scikit-learn.org.